# How to loop an Multidimentional Object-Array then create a HTML Nested List?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

```
var array = {
'Brazilians': ['Thalison', 'Allan'],
'Venezuelans': ['Jaime', 'Andres'],
 }
```

I just learned how to display the array with this:

```
 for (key in array) {

      document.write(`${key}: ${array[key]}<br>`);

      console.log(`${key}: ${array[key]}`);
 }
```

I hope to get this result with

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        Brazilians
        <ul>
            <li>Thalison</li>
            <li>Allan</li>
        </ul>.....
```

Comment: What should the output look like? Please steer clear of `document.write`, it is ancient technology, nowadays we have very good alternatives, like [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create new HTML elements and append them to the DOM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I just want a <ul> with <li> 'Brazilians' and 'Venezuelan', then each of them with their own list

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = {
  'Brazilians': ['Thalison', 'Allan'],
  'Venezuelans': ['Jaime', 'Andres'],
}

const createItem = (text) => {
       const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerText = text;
      return li
}

 for (key in array) {
    const ul = document.createElement('ul')
    const li = createItem(key)
    li.style.fontWeight = 'bold'
    ul.append(li)
    array[key].forEach(item => { 
      const li = createItem(item)
      ul.append(li)
    })
    document.body.append(ul)
 }
```

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

First of: **never use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)**. Even the documentation recommends against using it and gives some reason to why you shouldn't use it.

---

One way to create HTML in JavaScript is with [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). This function can create HTML elements, which you can then append to the DOM with the [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) method that every HTML Element has.

In the example below I've used a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop in combination with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). While `for...in` can be used to iterate over objects, the `for...of` loop is recommended as it only loops over values that should be looped over. [See the difference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#difference_between_for...of_and_for...in).
`Object.keys()` turn all the property keys into an array of keys. So the result in this case would be `['Brazilians', 'Venezuelans']` where we in turn loop over.

Inside the loop we create a second loop where we loop over the names array of each property in the object.

```js
var data = {
  'Brazilians': ['Thalison', 'Allan'],
  'Venezuelans': ['Jaime', 'Andres'],
}

// First create the outer list.
const list = document.createElement('ul');

// Loop over the keys of the object.
for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
  // Create a list item for every key.
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = key;
  
  // Create the sub list.
  const subList = document.createElement('ul');
  
  // Loop over the nested array.
  for (let name of data[key]) {
    // Create a sub list item for every name.
    const subListItem = document.createElement('li');
    subListItem.textContent = name;
    
    // Add the sub list item to the sub list.
    subList.append(subListItem);
  }
  
  // Add the sub list to the list item.
  listItem.append(subList);
  
  // Add the list item to the list.
  list.append(listItem);
}

// Add the list to the body.
document.body.append(list);
```

Comment: Very detailed answer, I am aware that I shouldn't use document.write for a project, I just use it as an alternative for console.log() since there's no echo in javascript.

Really thanks for taking your time to answer my question!! Your output is amazing.